# Can we define $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\left\backslash \left\{ 0\right\} \right.$?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Consider $$z^{\frac{1}{2}}:=e^{\frac{1}{2}(\log|z|+iarg(z))}.$$

We can see that, for example, $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ can be defined as a holomorphic function near $z=\frac{1}{2}$, by chossing a very small neighbourhood of $z=\frac{1}{2}$, and define an appropriate $arg(z)$ to make it continuous there.

My question: Can $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ be considered as a holomorphic function on $D\left\backslash \left\{ 0\right\} \right.$? Here $D$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$.

By *holomorphic function* I mean that a map $f:D\left\backslash \left\{ 0\right\} \right.\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation on $D\left\backslash \left\{ 0\right\} \right.$.

*As answered below*, we see that the answer for my question is negative. I would like to consider the following extra related question:

**An extra question**: similar question but this time we consider the domain $D\left\backslash B(0,\epsilon) \right.$, for a very small $\epsilon$.

Comment: No. I gave an explanation why in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3783606/774222

Comment: The function is not even continuous on all of $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: I 've editted my question with an extra part. I think it would be quite different now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This function would be bounded in a punctured neighborhood of $0$, which would make $0$ a removable singularity of $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$. But then $0$ would also be a removable singularity of the derivative $\frac{1}{2z^{\frac{1}{2}}}$, which can't have a removable singularity at $0$ because it isn't bounded in a punctured neighborhood.

Comment: Thks, would you have a look at my extra question.

Comment: @Hana: then it would be defined on an annulus centered at zero, so it would have a Laurent series expansion around zero. The square of this series would be just $z$, a power series, so the original Laurent series should also be a power series (can probably prove it using Cauchy product formula). But then it could be analytically extended to the whole disc, which should probably lead to a similar contradiction as above.

Comment: Thks, I got it now.